# Why doesn't my click handler work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this link

```
<a class="tt-link" data-link="report.html?id=0">Open</a>
```

I want to open it in a new tab so I attach a handler in my ready()

```
 $('.tt-link').click(function(event){
        console.log(event.target.data('link'));
        window.open('url', '_blank');
    });
```

This doesn't work like my selector is wrong, but it's not. No console output no matter what.

Comment: Where did you put the code? Before or after the actual link?

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on the *open* link in your jsfiddle example produces the following error in the console:

> event.target.data is not a function

Since you're using jQuery you should use `$(this)` to access the element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tt-link', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('link'));
  window.open('url', '_blank');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/7xwEq/).

Comment: Doesn't work. The handler doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Yes it does. Did you look at the fiddle I made? It adds `report.html?id=0` to the console and opens a new window.

Comment: And ensure that your code goes in a ready function like @putvande suggests too.

Comment: Just in case you're adding the link to the DOM after the page has loaded, I've updated my answer to allow for [event delegation/bubbling](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to place your code within `$(function(){ ... }` (but also use `$(this)` instead of `event.target`:

```
$(function(){
    $('.tt-link').click(function(event){
        console.log($(this).data('link'));
        window.open('url', '_blank');
    });
});
```